# fontawesome issue - dynamically generating html table with javascript with fontawesome

Tags: javascript, font-awesome-5

I am able to generate the html table using the javascript code, but the fontawesome icon is not appearing. I tried so many things but still the same issue.

Here is the code snippet:

```
var tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
tableBody.appendChild(tr);
var td1 = document.createElement('td');
td1.setAttribute("class","fas fa-file-pdf");
td1.appendChild("<span class='fas fa-file-pdf'></span>");
tr.appendChild(td1);
```

I also tried below code and it is also not working:

```
content +="<tr><td><i class='fas fa-file-pdf fa-2x'></i></td><td>N/A2</td><td>N/A3</td><td>N/A4</td></tr>
```

For testing purpose, I created the dummy html table and it is working as expected:

```
<table>
   <tr><td><span class='fas fa-file-pdf fa-2x'></span></td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td> <td>4</td></tr>
   <tr><td><i class="fas fa-file-pdf fa-2x"></i></td><td>N/A2</td><td>N/A3</td><td>N/A4</td></tr>
  </table>
```

imports I am using is

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-+Ga2s7YBbhOD6nie0DzrZpJes+b2K1xkpKxTFFcx59QmVPaSA8c7pycsNaFwUK6l" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-7ox8Q2yzO/uWircfojVuCQOZl+ZZBg2D2J5nkpLqzH1HY0C1dHlTKIbpRz/LG23c" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This issue would be easier to diagnose if you could create a reproducible test case using https://jsfiddle.net/ because we could see the javascript console and debug you running code.

Answer (score 0):

```
content +='<tr><td><i class="fas fa-file-pdf fa-2x"></i></td><td>N/A2</td><td>N/A3</td><td>N/A4</td></tr>'
```

This should work. just switch ' with "

Comment: I just tried and its not working. The 1st <td> is empty.

Comment: Does it render something else? If the rendered code is the same then look in devtools->css wether fa is loaded.

Comment: The 1st <td> is empty.

Comment: Then something else is wrong. Try to make a little jsfiddle with your code and append it to your question.

Comment: I create the demo page and I was not able to reproduce the issue. I finally copied the html generated for the fontawesome icon and it worked.  Thank you for the help.